# Xcode 14.1: Error: UINavigationBar decoded as unlocked for UINavigationController, or navigationBar delegate set up incorrectly.?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode14

What does it mean ? I haven't added UINavigationBar in my project. UINavigationController is embedded through editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.

> [Assert] UINavigationBar decoded as unlocked for UINavigationController, or navigationBar delegate set up incorrectly. Inconsistent configuration may cause problems. navigationController=<UINavigationController: 0x13b80c600>, navigationBar=<UINavigationBar: 0x13b5079f0; frame = (0 0; 0 50); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000f56620>> delegate=0x13b80c600

Comment: I just started seeing this with iOS 16.1/Xcode 14.1. So far it's been a benign error. My guess Apple will have it fixed soon. But it can't hurt to submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: yes, only seeing this in iOS 16.1/Xcode 14.1

Comment: See also: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714278?page=2